# Updating constraint doesn't change frame

Tags: ios, objective-c, nslayoutconstraint

For some reason, when I change constant of a constraint, it doesn't change the frame.

Most threads I've read suggested calling `layoutIfNeeded` after changing the constraint, but that doesn't seem to work for me.

My view hierarchy looks like this:

```
self.parentViewController.view
   self.view
     self.contentView
        a bunch of text fields here
```

`self.view` is added as a subview on `parentViewController.view` because it needs to behave similar to a UIAlertView. (Self is also added as childViewController).

I have a constraint between `topLayoutGuide` and `self.contentView.top` which has an outlet called `topConstraint`.

When the keyboard is shown, I execute the following method:

```
- (void)keyboardWillShow:(NSNotification*)notification {
    //Currently using a constant value and no animation for debugging.
    [self.topConstraint setConstant:20];
    [self.view setNeedsUpdateConstraints];
    [self.view layoutIfNeeded];
}
```

I made sure `keyboardWillShow` is executed, as well as I've printed `self.topConstraint` in `keyboardWillHide` method and the constant value is set to 20 yet no frame has changed.

Any idea what the problem could be?

**Edit: Something VERY interesting, if I rotate the device, self.contentView's frame changes.**

Edit: As suggested, I tried adding the constraint from code, still no good. (I deleted all constraints in storyboard besides constantHeight and constantWidth of self.contentView):

```
self.verticalSpace = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:self.contentView
                                                  attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop
                                                  relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                     toItem:self.view
                                                  attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop
                                                 multiplier:1.0f
                                                   constant:20];
[self.view addConstraint:self.verticalSpace];
[self.view setNeedsUpdateConstraints];
[self.view layoutIfNeeded];
```

**Edit2: Currently self.parentViewController inherits from ECSlidingViewController, but if I change that into UIViewController, it works as expected.**

Comment: How do you create the constraint?

Comment: From the storyboard (I said I have an outlet to it).

Comment: Yep I don't know if you are having the same problem as I did, but I wasn't able to outlet constrain, never could make it work, at last I created it programatically and then it worked. Sounds like something that is happening to you.

Comment: Does removing `[self.view setNeedsUpdateConstraints];` help?

Comment: In terms of adding constraints programatically, you need to use the `topLayoutGuide` property of `UIViewController`

Comment: I tried with self.topLayoutGuide as well as self.view, still no good.

Comment: Hi create Iboutlet of your constraints, and change run time when you need, then always call  **[super updateViewConstraints]**;

Comment: I added `[super updateViewConstraints];` to the `keyboardWillShow` method, no change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For some reason, if my view controller inherited ECSlidingViewController, `Autolayout` wasn't working, no matter what I did.

So instead, I made an `InitialViewController` which had `ECSlidingViewController` as property and I was adding its view as a subview to my `InitialViewController`'s view:

```
[self.view addSubview:self.slidingViewContoller.view];
[self addChildViewController:self.slidingViewContoller];
```

So my view hierarchy now looks like this:

```
initialViewController.view
   slidingViewController.view
```

And when I added `self.view`, I added it to `initialViewController.view` instead of adding it to `slidingViewController.view`.

After that, my view hierarchy looked like:

```
initialViewController.view
   slidingViewController.view
   self.view
      self.contentView
        textFields
```